# Problems working with custom databases for the LOLA package

Tags: r, data.table, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I recently started using the [LOLA package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/LOLA.html) in R and ran into a problem, after entering custom databases into the runLOLA function, it gives an error.

```
runLOLA(GR_hyper_M45X_maXX,GR_LAD,GR_matXX_without_meth_diff,redefineUserSets   = T)
Error in `:=`(dbSet, seq_len(nrow(annotationDT))) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=")
```

I tried to change the database type from a regular table to a Range object , but nevertheless the error remained the same.

I would be glad for any help, thank you.

Comment: What is the structure of `GR_matXX_without_meth_diff`?  Is it a list with an element name `regionAnno`?  That element should be of class datatable, or you will get the above error..   You can try `library(data.table); setDT(GR_matXX_without_meth_diff[["regionAnno"]])`

Comment: All datasets, including GR_matXX_without_meth_def have the form grange object: chr start-stop. Now I will try the proposed method, thank you for your help)